# .Net Core 5.0 - Sql Azure + Always Encrypted + Managed Identity

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I have a Azure SQL Db with encrypted columns (Always Encrypted with Azure KeyVault). I can access this db from SSMS and I can see the decrypted data.

I also have a web app made with .Net Core 5.0 which is deployed to Azure App Service. The app service has Managed Identity turned on and Key Vault that has enc/dec keys for that SQL Db has access policy setting to permit this app service to decrypt the data.

The web app works with managed identity as I can see that not encrypted data is retrieved without any issue.

Also, connection string does include `Column Encryption Setting=enabled;`. Here's the connection string:

```
Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=somedb;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;
```

The problem is I can't find ANY samples with this kind of set up. I found some and I understand I need to register `SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider`. Here's my code to obtain SqlConnection:

```
    internal static class AzureSqlConnection
    {
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        private static void InitKeyVaultProvider(ILogger logger)
        {
            /*
             * from here - https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/release-notes/add-ons/AzureKeyVaultProvider/1.2/1.2.0.md
             *      and  - https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/doc/samples/AzureKeyVaultProviderExample.cs
             *
             */

            try
            {
                // Initialize AKV provider
                SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider =
                    new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(AzureActiveDirectoryAuthenticationCallback);

                // Register AKV provider
                SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(
                    new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>(1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    {
                        {SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider}
                    });

                _isInitialized = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "Could not register SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider");
                throw;
            }
        }

        internal static async Task<SqlConnection> GetSqlConnection(string connectionString, ILogger logger)
        {
            if (!_isInitialized) InitKeyVaultProvider(logger);

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                /*
                         * This is Managed Identity (not Always Encrypted)
                         *  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#modify-aspnet-core
                         *
                         */
#if !DEBUG
                conn.AccessToken = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
                logger.LogInformation($"token: {conn.AccessToken}");
#endif
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                return conn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "Could not establish a connection to SQL Server");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> AzureActiveDirectoryAuthenticationCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope)
        {
            return await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

            //AuthenticationContext? authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            //ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(s_clientId, s_clientSecret);
            //AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
            //if (result == null)
            //{
            //    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to retrieve an access token for {resource}");
            //}

            //return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

This code does not throw any exceptions, and it works for non-encrypted queries. But for encrypted queries I get the following error:

> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered) custom key store provider names are: . Please verify key store provider information in column master key definitions in the database, and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are registered properly. Failed to decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered) custom key store provider names are: . Please verify key store provider information in column master key definitions in the database, and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are registered properly.

It seems like the key vault provider is not registered.

What should I do to make it work to query encrypted data?

## packages used

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Comment: Does this help? It looks like the same problem although the accepted answer doesn't seem to apply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618582/sql-always-encrypted-in-azure

Comment: I feel your pain.... this is _almost_ helpful but not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-2017#making-azure-key-vault-keys-available-to-applications-and-users

Comment: Could you please provide the access policy you configure fro the MSI?

Comment: As usual: Key: Get, List; Crypto: Unwrap, Wrap, Verify, Sign. Otherwise it wouldn't work anywhere else.
I believe Key-List is not really needed. But it's there anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, it is impossible to read decrypted data in .NET 5 when MSI is used. There is a bug in MS packages and the app service is never authorized.

You have to use Service Principal. This works like a charm!

## Update

I have to thank to MS engineers that offered a working solution:

```
public static async Task<string> KeyVaultAuthenticationCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
     return await Task.Run(() => new ManagedIdentityCredential().GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new string [] {"https://vault.azure.net/.default"})).Token);
     /********************** Alternatively, to use User Assigned Managed Identity ****************/
     // var clientId = {clientId_of_UserAssigned_Identity};
     // return await Task.Run(() => new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId).GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new string [] {"https://vault.azure.net/.default"})).Token);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use this code that uses provides a TokenCredential to the SqlColumnEncryption provider. DefaultAzureCredential returns a managed identity when deployed as an App Service:

```
            SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers = new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>
            {
                { SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider }
            };
            SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
```

Call it from your startup.Configure method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with .NET 5. You've taken the example authentication callback for Azure Key Vault and changed it to be specific to Azure SQL DB instead of the AKV resource. You need to adjust your callback to get a valid AKV token. This is just one way to get a token using the Azure.Core and Azure.Identity libraries:

```
    private static async Task<string> AzureActiveDirectoryAuthenticationCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => new ManagedIdentityCredential().GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new string [] {"https://vault.azure.net/.default"})).Token);
    }
```

Comment: Except this doesn't work. I tried it - https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/847#issuecomment-754111237

Comment: I was mainly just pointing out your error. Your answer made a blanket statement that was simply incorrect:
"it is impossible to read decrypted data in .NET 5 when MSI is used. There is a bug in MS packages and the app service is never authorized."
I was trying to point you in the direction that there are solutions and you are lumping encryption, MSI, and .NET 5 all together when that grouping makes no sense. They are all independent features. You need to implement the correct code that makes them work. Specifically, code that retrieves the correct access token for accessing Azure key vault.

Comment: got it. yes, MS guys gave me some ideas (and code!) to try. So I'll be working on it this week and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider` v3

```cs
SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new(new ManagedIdentityCredential());

Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers = new()
{
    [SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName] = azureKeyVaultProvider
};

SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
```

Taken from [`microsoft/sql-server-samples`](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/security/ledger/source/ContosoHR/Startup.cs#L88) after almost losing my mind.

Apart from that, it's required to:

- Assign app service managed identity `Key Vault Crypto User` role in Key Vault's IAM tab.
- Grant app service managed identity DB user `VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION` and `VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION` permissions:

  ```sql
  GRANT VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION to [app-service-user]
  GRANT VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION to [app-service-user]
  ```
- Allow app service access through Key Vault's firewall (i.e. adding app service outbound IPs to Key Vault's firewall rules).